# how deal with non-negatively of error in the model?

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to solve a quadratic program in R. Since my matrix Dmat is not positive definite I am using dykstra to solve it. my model is:

```
           min W^T* Dmat *W +epsilon
            Wx+b >= 1- epsilon
             epsilon >=0
```

my problem is I have 9000 row constraints and so 9000 epsilon. when I add epsilon>=0 to Amat, I am adding a 9000 more row in my matrix Amat. this make the dykstra very slow and hard to solve. without adding these constraints my model is solved in 1 minutes but after adding these I can not get result. more than 1 day....
Is there any way to deal with these constraints, both in modelling and solving?

Comment: Can you provide a small sized example and code of your use case. I think the dykstra needs a positive definite matrix. Furthermore, epsilon often used to name the numeric tolerance in the algorithm and in your question it seems to be a vector of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If your $D$ matrix is not positive definite, the problem is a non-convex QP (assuming I read the problem correctly). This is a very difficult problem to solve. You need a global solver for this. Cplex has a parallel non-convex QP solver which can solve reasonably sized problems. There is also a (non-trivial) way to linearize this into a mixed-integer programming model [(link)](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/06/solving-non-convex-qp-problems-as-mip.html). That would allow you to use to high-performance parallel MIP solvers.

If your problem is only very slightly non-convex, you may be able to perturb the diagonal of $D$ and make the problem convex. This is sometimes useful if some  roundoff errors caused $D$ to be not positive definite.

Note that problem is somewhat difficult to read. What are the variables in the model? If $x$ and $W$ are both variables, you also have a non-linear constraint, which makes things much more complicated. If $W$ is a matrix, we don't have a proper objective. So in the above answer, I assumed $x$ is a data matrix and $W$ is variable vector.